# Meaning of "avant-veille"?

Tags: sens, transcription

In this record, does the highlighted term mean … ?

- yesterday
- day before yesterday
- day before the date of burial in the first line
- something else

[image]

Transcription (with my errors corrected by others—thanks!):

> Le douze avril de l'an mil neuf cent deux, nous soussigné, curé de
> Saint Casimir de Ripon, avons inhumé dans le cimetière de cette
> paroisse le corps de Marie Frappier veuve de David Groslo de cette
> paroisse.  Elle est décédée en cette paroisse l’***avant-veille*** à l'âge
> de quatre-vingt six ans cinq mois et dix jours et inhumée en présence
> des soussignés qui ont signé avec nous, lecture faite.
> Dorcineau Desjardins, Albert Desjardins, Gatien Frédéric Paquette, ? Desjardins,
> J.J. Desjardins, Renée? Desjardins, ? Desjardins.

Comment: In those days, the bearers of the name were illiterate and the priests spelled it Grolo, Groslo, Grolot, & Groslot.  Later on, Grosleau became the consensus, but since 1900 it's been Groleau.  I fond one instance each of Groslos, Grosleaux, and Groleaux.  We've joked that our name could mean "fat chance" or "Jackpot."  One relative decided he should anglicize it to "Bigelow".

Comment: it helps to know that "la veille"  means "the day before", and not just "yesterday"

Comment: That was my guess, but Toto's answer says _two_ days before.

Comment: yes, "veille", the day before ; "avant-veille", the day before the day before, i.e. 2 days before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> le décès a eu lieu l'avant veille du jour de l'inhumation.

Soit deux jours avant. *Two days before*.

L'inhumation a eu lieu le 12 avril 1912, la date de décès est donc le 10 avril 1912.